# how to turn all rows before max value to zero in a data frame? python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

how can I turn all values in each column of a dataframe that occur before the maximum value into zero for instance column A = 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3 and column B = 2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4. after performing a single operation or function how can I get the values in the columns to be: column A= 0,0,0,0,5,1,2,3 and column B= 0,0,0,0,0,7,3,4.

ive tried using dataframe.where, tried using loc and iloc but it was no use as I was not able to compare the index of the maximum value to the index of every row(in all the columns) so that I could find which rows were at an index lesser than the index of the max value in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need `idxmax`:

```
print(df.idxmax())
A    4
B    5
dtype: int64
```

or using `mul`:

```
df = df.mul(df.eq(df.max()).cumsum())
# or if more than one place there is a max value
# df = df.mul(df.eq(df.max()).cumsum().gt(0))

print(df)
   A  B
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  0  0
4  5  0
5  1  7
6  2  3
7  3  4
```

Comment: ok its working this part df = df.mul(df.eq(df.max()).cumsum().gt(0)) thanks so much ill mark your answer as correct

Comment: thankyou so much Sandeep Kadapa its working ur great!

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]

print(max(A))

newA = []
maxValueFound = False
for i in A:
    if(i>=max(A) or maxValueFound==True):
        newA.append(i)
        maxValueFound = True
    else:
        newA.append(0)

print(newA)
```

> **Output:**
>   [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: thanks for the help, I get the general idea but how can I apply this to entire dataframe do you have any idea? (the dataframe contains above a million rows)